# Mysql Inner join condition after ON and WHERE performance

Tags: mysql

i have a tables Table1 and Table2,
now i want to use join between those 2 tables,

like

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 t1 JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.field1 = t2.field2 AND t1.enableFlag=0;
```

and now i use `t1.enableFlag=0` in where clause instaed of `JOIN...ON` like

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 t1 JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.field1 = t2.field2 WHERE t1.enableFlag=0;
```

than which is good for mysql performance.

Comment: It depends on the MySQL version, look at the query plan to see if they're different at all

Comment: I tried EXPLAIN EXTENDED for both query and result is same for both.

Comment: In that case it makes no difference for your query and both should perform equally well :)

Comment: that i know but want to know that is there any performance wise benifit?.

Comment: There is no performance benefit. If explain returns the same result MySQL will execute it the same way. Your MySQL version recognizes that both queries are identical.